# Copying wiki tags from other SE

Tags: discussion

I've copied the tag description for [unity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) from [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity): is this considered ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, we'd rather you not just blindly copy the contents for a tag from one SE site to another. The tags, though the same name, may mean very different things to the various SE communities.

Just my $0.02.

Comment: You're right, I've noticed here it referred to the gnome unity, apparently.

Comment: Still, the question stands: I'll create a tag [tag:unity3d], and would it be fine to just copy the description?

Comment: @Lohoris - I would ask your Q of can we create a tag for X and refer to the other sites tags in the request. Then let the community decide here. Unity is a desktop in Ubuntu which is 100x more relevant here than what you're trying to reference.